# Avoid repeated code handling buttons

Tags: android, button

This a simple sequencer with 16 buttons, each triggering a sample. My guess is that this can be done in a more elegant way (not writing 16 times the same). But how?

```
    @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn, boolean playing) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (btn == tgl1) {
        if (playing) {
            s1.seekTo(0);
            s1.start();
        } else {
            s1.pause();
        }

    }
    if (btn == tgl2) {
        if (playing) {
            s2.seekTo(0);
            s2.start();
        } else {
            s2.pause();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add you buttons to a `Map<CompoundButton, MediaPlayer>`. Then you can use a lookup on the button to get the `s2` or `sN` object.

```
map.put(button1, s1);
map.put(button2, s2);
// And so on.

MediaPlayer s = map.get(btn);
if (playing) {
    s.seekTo(0);
    s.start();
} else {
    s.pause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign an identifier to each button and each sample.
2. When a button is pressed, pick a sample corresponding to the identifier in the button and start playing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a map from each button id to the sample, and populate it on startup. Then, you can just do:

```
s = samplesMap.get(btn.getId());
if(playing) {
    s.seekTo(0);
    s.start();
} else {
    s.pause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have 16 different buttons and you have 16 different `MediaPlayer` instances to operate on each button. If so one way could be

1. Create a `Hashmap<Button, MediaPlayer>`
2. For each button use the
   player for that